# what do you call a circle with every number around it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, circles, projective-space

[image: this guy]

What do you call this Zeno-ish circle? It has every single number around it.

The numbers are placed at $1/4, 3/8, 7/16, 15/36$ and so on.

Basically $2^{n-1}/2^{n+1}$ for the positives, and $-2^{-n-1}/2^{-n+1}$ for the negatives.

Comment: I think you're talking about the [projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line).

Comment: yeah this one's the answer how do i pin it

Comment: I'll add as an answer. Did you only wanted to know the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're talking about the [projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line).